# Compare two fields from two tables where the values are not exact matches

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I'm trying to compare two tables with *similar* but not *exact* values.

Table 1 looks like:

```
Group     ID    
G1        101939    
G1        181933            
G3        291940
```

Table 2 looks like

```
Group     ID      
G1        101939R
G1        101939L
G1        181933R
G2        201943R   
G2        241947L   
G3        291940R
```

I would like to return something like this:

```
Group     ID        Match?
G1        101939R   Yes
G1        101939L   Yes
G1        181933R   Yes
G2        201943R   No
G2        241947L   No
G3        291940R   Yes
```

Basically table 2 has more IDs than table 1, and some of them match for all but the last character.

Comment: Can you post a query that you've tried?

Comment: Are the values unique in each table? Data types? Basically, your table definitions should be in the question (`\d tbl`in psql). Also, are there always 6 digits or is your example misleading? Do groups have to match? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an explicit `join` or `exists` clause:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table1 t1
                          where t1.group = t2.group and
                                t2.id like t1.id || '_'
                         )
        then 'Yes' else 'No'
        end) as Matches
from table2 t2;
```

If you want to allow exact matches as well as the ones missing the last character, use:

```
                          where t1.group = t2.group and
                                (t2.id like t1.id || '_' or t2.id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if all the groups are listed in `table2` and the ID's begin with six numbers that need to be compared:

```
SELECT t2."group", t2.id, t1.id IS NOT NULL
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON (t1."group" = t2."group" AND t1.id = SUBSTRING(t2.id for 6)::INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `left(id, -1)` as simplest and fastest way to trim the last character:

```
SELECT *, EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl1 WHERE t1.id = left(t2.id, -1)) AS match
FROM   tbl2 t2
```

Nothing in your question indicates that groups have to match ...